# binding two data frames in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, data-manipulation

I have two data frames:

1).

```
                          2017 Hours
name            Month   

a               January   199.25
                February  203.25
                March     220.75
                April     203.50
                May       242.50
                June      261.25
                July      278.50
                August    227.75
                September 160.75
                October   213.50
                November  230.75
                December  159.75


                          2018 Hours 
name            Month   

a               January   199.25
                February  203.25
                March     220.75
                April     203.50
                May       242.50
                June      261.25
                July      278.50
                August    227.75
                September 160.75
                October   213.50
                November  230.75
                December  159.75
```

I want to combine the two data frames into one for plotting. My goal is to plot a simple line graph with Hours on the y-axis and Months on the x-axis with a line for 2017 and another for 2018

I want a df that looks like this:

```
                                       Hours
name            Month     Year

a               January   2017         199.25
                February  2017         203.25
                March     2017         220.75
                April     2017         203.50
                May       2017         242.50
                June      2017         261.25
                July      2017         278.50
                August    2017         227.75
                September 2017         160.75
                October   2017         213.50
                November  2017         230.75
                December  2017         159.7o
                January   2018         199.25
                February  2018         203.25
                March     2018         220.75
                April     2018         203.50
                May       2018         242.50
                June      2018         261.25
                July      2018         278.50
                August    2018         227.75
                September 2018         160.75
                October   2018         213.50
                November  2018         230.75
                December  2018         159.75
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need first set same column names in both `DataFrame`s, then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with parameter `keys` for distingush `DataFrame`s and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for columns from `MultiIndex`:

```
df1.columns = ['Hour']
df2.columns = ['Hour']
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=(2017, 2018)).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0':'Year'})
print (df)
    Year name      Month    Hour
0   2017    a    January  199.25
1   2017    a   February  203.25
2   2017    a      March  220.75
3   2017    a      April  203.50
4   2017    a        May  242.50
5   2017    a       June  261.25
6   2017    a       July  278.50
7   2017    a     August  227.75
8   2017    a  September  160.75
9   2017    a    October  213.50
10  2017    a   November  230.75
11  2017    a   December  159.75
12  2018    a    January  199.25
13  2018    a   February  203.25
14  2018    a      March  220.75
15  2018    a      April  203.50
16  2018    a        May  242.50
17  2018    a       June  261.25
18  2018    a       July  278.50
19  2018    a     August  227.75
20  2018    a  September  160.75
21  2018    a    October  213.50
22  2018    a   November  230.75
23  2018    a   December  159.75
```

But for ploting should be better:

```
df = (pd.concat([df1['2017 Hours'], df2['2018 Hours']], keys=(2017, 2018), axis=1)
       .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
print (df)
             2017    2018
Month                    
January    199.25  199.25
February   203.25  203.25
March      220.75  220.75
April      203.50  203.50
May        242.50  242.50
June       261.25  261.25
July       278.50  278.50
August     227.75  227.75
September  160.75  160.75
October    213.50  213.50
November   230.75  230.75
December   159.75  159.75
```

Comment: Thanks this work and makes sense to have two different columns for both years. However, I still need the "name" column since there different names which plan it iterate over and create a plot for each name. How, do I add the name column back into the df. Also, how would I go about plotting this??

Comment: Try remove `.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Pass to multiple index

```
df1.columns=df1.columns.str.split(' ',expand=True)

df1.swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).stack()
Out[946]:
                     Hours
name Month
a    January  2017  199.25
     February 2017  203.25
     March    2017  220.75

df2.columns=df2.columns.str.split(' ',expand=True)
```

Then

Using concat

```
pd.concat([df1.swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).stack(),df2.swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).stack()])
```